# Get last 3 characters of every list element and change it to # with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of list of phone number on HTML. 
I need to replace every last 3 digits with ###.

What is the best approach to do this with pure Javascript?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">333444555</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">777888999</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The expected result should be something like this

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">333444###</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">777888###</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Appreciate all answers..

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements with a class of "phone", then loop through them returning a new string without the last 3 characters by using [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), finally concatenate the `###`:

```js
var phones = document.querySelectorAll('.phone');
phones.forEach(function(p){
  var t = p.textContent;
  p.textContent = t.slice(0, -3) + '###';
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">333444555</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">777888999</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querSelectorAll` and `replace`

```
.{3}$
```

- `.{3}` - Match anything except new line 3 times
- `$` - End of string

```js
var phones = document.querySelectorAll('.phone');
phones.forEach(function(p){
  var t = p.textContent;
  p.textContent = t.replace(/.{3}$/, '###');
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">333444555</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="phone">777888999</dd>
      </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var phones = document.querySelectorAll('.phone');
phones.forEach(function(p) {
  p.textContent = p.textContent.toString().slice(0, -3) + '###';
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>Phone:</dt>
      <dd class="phone">333444555</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>Phone:</dt>
      <dd class="phone">777888999</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note:- get all

tag value from the loop and convert it to `string` slice last three characters using `slice` and append `###`.

The simple way to do this.